# @Bean configuration of @Scheduled components

Tags: spring, spring-boot

First time looking at Spring - and I have a question regarding configuration of a bean that I also would like to schedule. 
Using Spring Boot, I've created a Application class, and a TaskClass that I would both like to Schedule and configure using a configuration class.

**Application Class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan("mmmi.pdws.cetrea")
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(PdwsBackend.class, args); //Leftover from Boot project

    ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);

    taskClass task = ctx.getBean(taskClass.class);
   }
}
```

**TaskClass**

```
@Component
public class TaskClass {
  private String taskName;

  @Scheduled(fixedRate=1000)
  public void lifeSign(){
     System.out.println("My name is " + taskName);
  }

  public void setName(String name){this.name = name}
}
```

**AppConfig class**

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
  @Bean
  public TaskClass taskClass(){
    TaskClass task = new TaskClass();
    task.setName("SpringTask");
    return task;
  }
}
```

The instantiated object from the Scheduler and from the AppConfig class are naturally not the same...but is there a way to configure the Scheduled object?

Looking at [Springs scheduling reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html) it seems to be doable with XML configuration? But what if I would like to do it with a Java configuration class?

Answer (score 0):

If the value that you want to set is constant, you can put it in your **application.properties** file and inject it to using the [@Value](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html) annotation directly into the scheduler bean.

**application.properties**

```
task.name=SpringTask
```

**TaskClass**

```
@Component
public class TaskClass {

  private final String taskName;

  public TaskClass(@Value("${task.name}") String taskName) {
     this.taskName = taskName;
  }

  @Scheduled(fixedRate=1000)
  public void lifeSign(){
     System.out.println("My name is " + taskName);
  }

  public void setName(String name){this.name = name}
}
```

You can also inject the value directly to the field if you don't like constructor injection.

Of course the bean declared in the `AppConfig` is redundant since the `TaskClass` is annotated with `@Component` and will be found by `@ComponentScan`.

Answer (score 0):

From the same spring ref [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html), you can read the following:

Make sure that you do not use `@Configurable` on bean classes which are annotated with `@Scheduled` and registered as regular Spring beans with the container: **You would get double initialization otherwise, once through the container and once through the `@Configurable` aspect**.

What you can do is simply use `@PostConstruct` method (called only once after bean creation) in your `TaskClass` to set `taskName` as shown below and then you don't need your `AppConfig` class:

```
    @Component
    public class TaskClass {

      private String taskName;

       @Postconstruct
       public void init() {
          taskName= "SpringTask";
       }

      @Scheduled(fixedRate=1000)
      public void lifeSign(){
         System.out.println("My name is " + taskName);
      }

      public void setName(String name){this.name = name}
    }
```